# Include additional resources in a jar

Tags: maven-2

I have compiled some class files and a jar file. Now i want to include some wsdl into the jar file .

Can you please tell me how can amend pom.xml in maven for achieving the same.

Regards
Gnash--85

Comment: Just put the WSDL in `src/main/resources`...

Answer (score 10):

Where do those WSDL files come from? 
Are they part of your source?

assuming you have

```
project
  + src
    + main
      + java
      + wsdl
      + resources
```

Please add in POM,

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      ...
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</directory>
      <resource>
    </resources>
   </build>
</project>
```

Then it should add your wsdl as extra resource

---

Edit:

There is an alternative way for which we don't need to update project.build.resources to include all resource directories.

This is by making use of [Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-wsdl-resource</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-resource</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That's good.  But I will suggest you changing the title to: 
"include additional resources to JAR" 
because the question really have nothing to do with WSDL.
And if it works, may you accept my answer? :) 

These saves time for other people searching for same issue :)